# Synthesizing an accessor for a member of a struct

Tags: objective-c

Let's say my object has a `CGRect` property named `rect`.

I want to maintain a single `CGRect` rather than individual `CGSize` and `CGPoint` (for comparison against other `CGRects` with `CGRectContainsRect()`) but I want accessors for the individual members so I don't have to recreate a whole new `CGRect` every time I want to change one or the other.

I thought I'd try:

```
@synthesize size = rect.size;
@synthesize position = rect.origin;
```

But the compiler didn't like that. Is there a way to do this without writing custom getter/setters?

Comment: Apple seems to use this style all over the place (check out UILabel for instance) _textLabelFlags. Would be great to be able to synthesize on a struct member...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The `@synthesize` directive can only take the names of instance variables, not arbitrary expressions.